# Perform groupBy with array of strings - Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have an array of strings defined in a variable which contains the name of the column. I would like to perform *group by* and get the count.

I am trying the below code, but it throws an error.

```
val keys = Array("Col1", "Col2")
val grouppedByDf = myDf.groupBy(keys.mkString(",").count
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(("βήτα", "άλφα", 20), ("άλφα", "βήτα", 10), ("άλφα", "βήτα", 20), ("βήτα", "άλφα", 10)).toDF("α", "β", "ω")
val keys = Array("α", "β")
df
  .groupBy(keys.map(col(_)): _*)
  .count()
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+-----+
|   α|   β|count|
+----+----+-----+
|βήτα|άλφα|    2|
|άλφα|βήτα|    2|
+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: This is working thanks. Can you please explain this: col(_)): _*

Comment: Considering the groupBy signature `groupBy(cols: Column*)` , `map(col(_))` applies/maps the col function to each element of the keys array, the result being a new Array[Column]. The `:_*` annotation, unpacks the elements of the new array and binds them to the varargs parameter `(cols:Columns*)` of the groupBy method.

Comment: Is this understanding correct - when mkstring is used, it converts the output into a single string - "Col1, Col2" and there is no column by that name - so the above solution converts it into col(Col1), col(Col2) and passes it to the group by ?

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75335727/edit) the explanation to the answer, please? (But *** *** *** *** ***without*** *** *** *** ***  "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)